# how do I import a local file which is not in the lib folder

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I import a local file, which is not in the 'lib' folder?

[image]

Comment: You should be following the conventions of https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout which will not require you to import anything outside lib or a local relative file.

Comment: ok, the lib folder works fine

Answer (score 0):

to import file from out side the lib folder you need to do the below steps

- Create your folder in your case (app)
- Inside the app folder create **pubspec.yaml** file and create **lib** folder
- Inside **lib** folder you can add your folder and files as (pages, my_app.dart)
- Inside the **pubspec.yaml** file do as folowing

> name: **outer_pubspec** # add the name you want here
>
> description: The Repo that handles users
>
> publish_to: 'none'
>
> version:0.0.1
>
> environment:
>
> sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'
>
> dependencies:
>
> flutter:
>
> sdk: flutter
>
> dev_dependencies:
>
> flutter_test:
>
> sdk: flutter
>
> flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
>
> flutter:   uses-material-design: true

- run pub get

Now in your main pubspec.yaml file under dependencies:

add the following

**outer_pubspec** is the name you added in the above pubspec.yaml

```
outer_pubspec:
  path: app
```

in the file you want to import to, use

import 'package:outer_pubspec/my_app.dart';

That's all.